# NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, railstutorial.org, minitest

There are some other threads tackling this issue, but none of them helped us fix our problem.

When we run one of our integration tests with Minitest, we get the following `ERROR`:

```
ERROR["test_index_including_pagination", UsersIndexTest, 2015-06-30 06:44:19 -0700]
 test_index_including_pagination#UsersIndexTest (1435671859.78s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
            test/test_helper.rb:20:in `log_in_as'
            test/integration/users_index_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
        test/test_helper.rb:20:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_index_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

Here is our `test_helper.rb` file:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

And here is the first part of our `users_index_test.rb` file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @admin     = users(:michael)
    @non_admin = users(:archer)
  end

  test "index including pagination" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.first_name + " " + user.first_name
    end
  end
```

Any idea why we get this `NoMethodError: undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `@user` was not initialized in your setup method. You initialize `@admin` and `@non_admin`, but not `@user`.